# Does somebody know what are the technologies behind the GitHub for Windows UI?

Tags: github-for-windows

Does somebody know what are the technologies behind the GitHub for Windows UI? It looks incredible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated by this [blog post](https://github.com/blog/1127-github-for-windows)

> We've mashed up the elegant **[Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/)** with **[Reactive Ui](http://www.reactiveui.net/)** to provide a responsive interface and to allow for greater testability.

For more information about Reactive Extensions, you can check Paul Betts' **[latest talk](http://vimeo.com/m/43659034)**, one of the creators of GitHub for Windows.

By the way, the "incredible look" may also come from the design research and work. You'll find some cover story of the UI topic in this post **[Designing GitHub for Windows](https://github.com/blog/1151-designing-github-for-windows)**, by Tim Clem, also one of the GfW creators.

Answer (score 3):

Github now releases more information at https://github.com/showcases/projects-that-power-github